# Not able to get taken Photo using default camera of ASUS_X01BDA in my app

Tags: android

In my app I have created a option for taking Photo and Viewing taken Photos.
For taking Photos I am using default camera of mobile.
I am using below code for passing intent

```
public  void intentForTakePicture() {

        Intent picIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (picIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Exception while trying to create image file!!");
            }

            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.app.photo.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                picIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(picIntent, TAKE_PHOTO);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"request code is: "+TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir("Pictures/photo/");
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
            currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "currentPhotoPath: " + currentPhotoPath);


        return image;
    }
```

In onActivityResult I am setting imageview whatever photos comes there

But the issue is, I am able to take photos but taken Photo is not getting back in onActivityResult.
Note: Getting this issue only for ASUS_X01BDA mobile.

I also checked the mobile camera permissions for my app. Got camera permission for my app.

I doesn't know the problem. 
Please Anybody help me to find the cause and to solve it

Comment: the code you showed is not much helpful, and you didn't show the code that likely is a problem - the onActivityResult

Comment: Are you getting a callback in onActivityResult or not, not a mind with null or anything

Comment: when you pass `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to camera intent, you will receive the photo saved in the file you sent as extra.

Comment: actually again I tried taking photo..now its working.But sometime photo is not getting